# could not launch process: stub exited while waiting for connection: exit status 0 in golang or vscode

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, apple-m1, goland

I have problems with my debugger go on a MacBook Pro M1 Pro.

When I try to debug my code I have this error:

```
"could not launch process: stub exited while waiting for connection: exit status 0"
```

I got this error when launching the debugger via VSCode, Goland and via the "dlv debug" command.

I wanted to know if someone had a solution to my problem.

Here is some information about my configuration:

```
go version go1.18.5 darwin/arm64
```

```
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.9.0
Build: $Id: 69310c2f438e492f892d6af22e8e62c8ea1e9d8d $
```

Comment: also you can reinstall XCode CLI Tools to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much, I just had to reinstall XCode CLI tools... I thought I had done it correctly but then the reinstallation worked.

Comment: @patricklamatiere were you encountering the error in your VSCode?  For me it works on iterm but not on the VScode integrated terminal! I get the identical error you were getting.
Also what did you use to reinstall XCode CLI Tools?

Comment: @ZeusLawyer, please see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375535

Comment: @s0xzwasd - thank you. Reinstalled, but still getting the same error from the VSCode integrated terminal.  Interestingly, not getting it in iterm! dlv debug works there.

Comment: @ZeusLawyer Hi, I had the same error everywhere no matter what terminal I use, just uninstall the XCode CLI Tools to run and I can debug from anywhere now.

Comment: Sadly didn't work for me :( may have to raise an issue on the vscode golang extension GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-installing XCode Command Line Tools should help.

- Delete a previous version of XCode Tools:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

- Install it from scratch:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 10):

None of the responses above worked for me. Then, after two days of research I saw someone saying that I should **install the M1 version of VSCode (not the universal version!)**

I had the "Universal" version, but when I checked Activity Monitor I found out that it was running as `Intel`. So I uninstalled it and downloaded the M1 version (specifically) from here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/download# (choose `Apple Silicon`).

Now debugging in VSCode works fine (I haven't tried in Goland).

Comment: I tried that too ! And uninstalled Rosetta but that broke a ton of other things. Dlv CLI now  works for me via iterm but not in integrated terminal ok vscode.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I was using the Universal version on M1 mac and after uninstalling the universal one and installing the M1 specific version, it worked for me. Did not do anything else other than installing the right version for the OS/Arch combination that works for M1 mac.

Comment: This was absolutely the answer for me, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check if running

```
sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Comment: Hi,
This command answered "Developer mode is already enabled."

Comment: Yep same for me.  And same confirmation on sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable